# Error in linking react-native-imagepicker

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image-picker

When I tried linking react-native-imagepicker with react-native it gives error :
Failed to get dependency config.

react-native-imagepicker @2.0.0
react-native@0.59.8

Comment: have you follow all the steps for linking?
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Install.md
if not then refer this.

Comment: @KishanGujarati yeah solved it. It was very naive mistake. I installed react-native-imagepicker but while  linking I uesd react-native-image-picker . That's the reason I got error, that( -) sign.

Comment: great
happy coding